# SwiftUI & Firebase: Does current user persist?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I am building an app with firebase login, and when I check for the current user, even when I start the simulator it will say that there is a current user. Is this correct and does the user persist?

Here is where I check for the user:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if authManager.signedIn {
                //Create a coordinator instance and inject it into the app
                HomeTabView()
            } else {
                InitialView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            print(authManager.signedIn)
            authManager.signedIn = authManager.isSignedIn
            print(authManager.signedIn)
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for the auth manager:

```
class authentication: ObservableObject {
    //Class that will handle logging in using firebase
    
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    @Published var signedIn: Bool = false
    private var firebaseLoggedIn: Bool = false
    private var localLoggedIn: Bool = false
    //Enabled will be triggered through the settings to allow the user the opportunity to use biometrics to login
    var enabled: Bool = false
    
    var isSignedIn: Bool {
        if auth.currentUser != nil {
            print (auth.currentUser?.email as Any)
        }
        return auth.currentUser != nil 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the user persists. However, I would recommend using an `authStateListener` and replacing your `authManager.signedIn = authManager.isSignedIn`, which seems like it could be fragile.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, I found that resetting the simulator to its initial settings cleared the cache of the current user so that works too

Answer (score 0):

Firebase automatically persists user credentials and tries to restore them when the app restarts. Note that this requires a call to the server, so it may not be done right when your app starts and so `currentUser` *may* still be `nil` at that point.

To ensure you get notified when the user credentials have been restored (or rejected by the server, such as when the account has been disabled), be sure to use an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet in the documentation n on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).